# how to select an element parent in scss

Tags: sass

Is there a way to get the **parent** of a **child** element in SCSS?

**html**

```
<div>
    <span>test1</span>
</div
<div>
    <p>dsdfds</p>
</div>
```

In the above example how can I style only the parent of an span element?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: If you're using jQuery, you could use `$(".parent > .child").parent().css("");`.

Comment: SCSS can't do anything that CSS can't. Until browsers start supporting [`:has`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-has), there is no way for SCSS/CSS to select parent elements.